# Horizontal Tearing DirectX9

Tags: c++, image, video, directx

I've been trying to develop a video capture display application with DirectX9 under Win7 using a vertex shader and a pixel shader (very basic ones).  However, the image being displayed is showing some tearing, always at the same location on the screen.  The specs are the following

- Video is being captured via a webcam
- Display is not in fullscreen mode
- Refresh rate of screen is 60Hz
- D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE is being used to force to a good refresh rate (found on some forum, doesn't work though)

I tried modifying this last parameter with all that are available only to realize that D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE gives me a consistent (always at the same position on screen) tearing.

I know that "enabling" V-Sync could maybe solve my problem, but I can't seem to find any info about this on the web (Yes I know, DirectX9 is getting outdated), so any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_DEFAULT` if it doesn't give you tearing.

This flag also enables V-sync. From documentation:

> D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_DEFAULT uses the default system timer resolution
>   whereas the D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE calls timeBeginPeriod to enhance
>   system timer resolution. This improves the quality of vertical sync,
>   but consumes slightly more processing time. Both parameters attempt to
>   synchronize vertically.